# Can I overlay images and texts on videos using Opengl in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, overlay, video-processing

I'm developing an Instagram Clone in android and I'm trying to mimic Stories feature. I'm confused about overlaying images and texts on videos and my question is can I use OpenGL to overlay images and texts on videos? If yes, how could I do?

Comment: Have you found some alternative?

Comment: FFmpeg is the alternative solution

Comment: How do you overlay text at random position and random angle on the image and make certain parts of that text clickable? How do you record the pixel positions?

Comment: I haven't tried it.